# Packages vs nodes

Tags: ros, package, node, best-practices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am writing a bunch of different nodes for a robot. I am trying to understand the difference between writing different nodes , each in its own package, versus putting all the nodes in the same package.

What are the benefits/drawbacks for either approach.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9133/packages-vs-nodes/) by [Yogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/105/yogi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 411 on 2011-02-19

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are no hard and fast rules. Some suggestions:

- Each ROS package is built as a unit:
- Pay attention to package dependencies. Avoid combining nodes that pull in mutually unneeded dependencies.
- Avoid combining nodes that are often used separately (to eliminate unnecessary build overhead).
- The overhead of an extra ROS package is not very large. Define separate packages wherever they make sense.
- If a group of nodes with similar dependencies are generally used together, consider combining them in a single package.
- If some nodes have common dependencies on shared code that you do not wish to export publicly, they can be combined internally within a single package.
- If the shared code should be exported, consider making it a separate package that the others depend on. (This is reasonable, but not required. A single package can export libraries and headers as well as nodes.)
- Choose package names carefully:
- Node names are local within their package, but package names are global to the entire ROS ecosystem.
- They are messy to change later.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 19